# IE 6 drop down on wordpress does not show

Tags: wordpress, menu, internet-explorer-6, drop-down-menu

I have implemented a drop down menu to my wordpress "header" template and for some reason the drop down does not show on IE6.  When I go to my index page, all works fine except there are no underline on the hovers.  When I switch to wordpress (under a sub directory) the drop down disappears.

I tried implementing whatever hover but it only works on the index page but not in my wordpress.  Wordpress doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

The css is as follows:

```
/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
#navDrop ul {
    background:#fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin:10px auto auto auto;
    left:-9999px;
}
#navDrop ul li{
    padding:1px; 
    float:none;
    background:#fff;
}
#navDrop ul a{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#navDrop li:hover ul{
    left:0;}

#navDrop li:hover a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navDrop li:hover ul a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#fff;
    width: 180px;
}
#navDrop li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
    background:#e4f2ff;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index:99999;
}
#navDrop li ul li {
    background:#fff;
    list-style:none;
    z-index:10001;
    padding:1px 0 0 0;
}
```

Your help is appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks i need the website to work on ie6 because it is a somewhat a requirement for this site... it is a medical site

Comment: why do u ask? no, i am filipino

Answer (score 2):

IE6 is really, really **dead**. http://www.ie6countdown.com/

That said, if you need to get dropdowns to work in IE6, check these two plugins and steal some code from them and also use the default WP theme twentyten's http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyten menu and doctype. The plugins use jQuery to support dropdowns in IE6.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twentyten-ie6-menus/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ie6-support-for-2010-theme/

Comment: I am using a template called http://blankcolumnrightsidebar.blankthemes.com/

I don't think it would be convenient to re style my wordpress blogs again... I am about 70% done, just trying to fix all the IE issues! I hate IE 6...

Comment: I'm not talking about restyling. Adapt the drop down menu code and IE6 fix to your theme style.

Comment: whoah... it kinda works! the container for the drop down menu however, the links, hovers do not show... is this a css issue?